# Solve the following Z-Transform Difference Equation

Tags: z-transform

We have this given equation

$$y_{n+1}- 2.5y_{n} = -1.1$$

With the initial condition of

$$y_{0} = \frac{1}{200}$$

All examples of this found on the internet have $y_{0}$ as an integer.

How can this be done when it's a fraction?

Comment: 1. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this website instead of html. 2. Why do you think anything should be different if $y_0$ isn't a whole number?

Comment: I have followed this video, (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3p6v2Q6aWOo&list=PL-5xe9pWYiGg2-LB4zi7FVyCMVMVzpJEM&index=8&t=499s) but when the check is done on the above example, it's not returning the expected result.

Comment: If you want help, you should put the information about how this example fails to behave as expected in your question via an [edit] - going and watching a youtube video is an unnecessary extra hurdle for people to jump before answering your question and helping you.